# Join two tbls of different size by factors in one and position of a certain value in the other one

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I am trying to join two differently sized tbls in R but a little bit stuck at the following point:

```
Tbl1:
A tibble: 27 x 2
             Value1 Factor
              <dbl> <fct>           
 1             0.39 10Y             
 2             0.39 10Y             
 3             0.17 10Y             
 4             0.17 10Y             
 5             0.11 10Y             
 6             0.11 10Y             
 7             0.03 10Y             
 8             0.03 15Y             
 9            11.9  15Y             
10            11.9  15Y             

Tbl2:
A tibble: 20 x 3
   Factor  Value2    Value3
   <fct>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 10Y    0            0.09
 2 10Y    0            1.01
 3 10Y    0.00500      5.01
 4 10Y    0.014        10.0 
 5 15Y    0            0.17
 6 15Y    0.001000     1.51
 7 15Y    0.012        6.01
 8 15Y    0.029        15.0 
 9 20Y    0            0.25
10 20Y    0.002        2.01
```

What I want to do is to match them first by the factor, i.e. "10Y" "15Y" etc, then pick the closest value in Tbl2Value3 to Tbl1Value1 and add a certain Value2 from tbl2 to a new column in Tbl1.

What I have tried so far is calculating the indices of those values in tbl2. Also tried intersect() to find intersecting factors.

```
indices <- array()
for (i in 1:nrow(tbl1)){
  indices[i] <- which(abs(tbl2$Value3 - tbls1$Value1[i])==min(abs(tbls2$Value3 - tbl1$Value1[i])))
}
```

Is there a better way to find the position of those values than which()? And how can I actually join the two together given all of the conditions above?

Really looking forward to your ideas!

Thanks a lot

P.S.: I apologise if my code hurt anyone's feelings... I am only learning. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, this can be solved using a *rolling join* with `data.table` where the parameter `roll = "nearest"` requests to find the nearest value for the last join condition `Value3 = Value1`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
    
result <- 
  setDT(Tbl2)[setDT(Tbl1), on = .(Factor, Value3 = Value1), roll = "nearest"] %>% 
  setnames("Value3", "Value1") %>% # clean up
  setcolorder(c("Value1", "Factor"))
result
```

> ```
>     Value1 Factor Value2
>  1:   0.39    10Y  0.000
>  2:   0.39    10Y  0.000
>  3:   0.17    10Y  0.000
>  4:   0.17    10Y  0.000
>  5:   0.11    10Y  0.000
>  6:   0.11    10Y  0.000
>  7:   0.03    10Y  0.000
>  8:   0.03    15Y  0.000
>  9:  11.90    15Y  0.029
> 10:  11.90    15Y  0.029
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)

Tbl1 <- fread("
rn           Value1 Factor
 1             0.39 10Y             
 2             0.39 10Y             
 3             0.17 10Y             
 4             0.17 10Y             
 5             0.11 10Y             
 6             0.11 10Y             
 7             0.03 10Y             
 8             0.03 15Y             
 9            11.9  15Y             
10            11.9  15Y", drop = 1L)

Tbl2 <- fread("
rn Factor  Value2    Value3
 1 10Y    0            0.09
 2 10Y    0            1.01
 3 10Y    0.00500      5.01
 4 10Y    0.014        10.0 
 5 15Y    0            0.17
 6 15Y    0.001000     1.51
 7 15Y    0.012        6.01
 8 15Y    0.029        15.0 
 9 20Y    0            0.25
10 20Y    0.002        2.01", drop = 1L)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses `inner_join` and then gets the `top_n` for each group. The `top_n` is weighted by absolute values of the difference of Value3 and Value1.

*Edit:* Also, I imported the `Factor` as a character. That makes the join easier as `inner_join` won't have to coerce the factor to character.

```
library(dplyr)

#add id to tb1
tbl1 <- mutate(tbl1, id = row_number())

inner_join(tbl1, tbl2, by = 'Factor')%>%
  group_by(Factor, id)%>%
  top_n(1, wt = desc(abs(Value3 - Value1)))%>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 5
   Value1 Factor    id Value2 Value3
    <dbl> <chr>  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   0.39 10Y        1  0       0.09
 2   0.39 10Y        2  0       0.09
 3   0.17 10Y        3  0       0.09
 4   0.17 10Y        4  0       0.09
 5   0.11 10Y        5  0       0.09
 6   0.11 10Y        6  0       0.09
 7   0.03 10Y        7  0       0.09
 8   0.03 15Y        8  0       0.17
 9  11.9  15Y        9  0.029  15   
10  11.9  15Y       10  0.029  15
```

And data:

```
tbl1 <- read.table(textConnection(             
'             Value1 Factor
 1             0.39 10Y             
 2             0.39 10Y             
 3             0.17 10Y             
 4             0.17 10Y             
 5             0.11 10Y             
 6             0.11 10Y             
 7             0.03 10Y             
 8             0.03 15Y             
 9            11.9  15Y             
10            11.9  15Y  '  ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tbl2 <- read.table(textConnection(
'   Factor  Value2    Value3
 1 10Y    0            0.09
 2 10Y    0            1.01
 3 10Y    0.00500      5.01
 4 10Y    0.014        10.0 
 5 15Y    0            0.17
 6 15Y    0.001000     1.51
 7 15Y    0.012        6.01
 8 15Y    0.029        15.0 
 9 20Y    0            0.25
10 20Y    0.002        2.01
'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```